# keras with tensorflow on GPU machine - some parts are very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm trying to train a model using keras \ tensorflow (1.4) on a p3.2xlarge aws machine (which has a NVIDIA Tesla V100 GPU)
two parts of the initialisation are very slow when using a GPU, but run in a reasonable time on CPU

The first part is "calling" an embedding layer during model setup

```
network = embedding(input)
```

this embedding layer is used several times, but only the 1st time is slow
it appears that this is the phase that the weights are copied to the GPU, and it takes a few minuets (~5) for a 400000 * 200 weight matrix

the second long part is the call to train_on_batch for the first batch (it takes about 20 minutes)

not sure it's relevant, but according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/boHj96fdIvM), it might be related to using a custom layer

are there any ways to speed up these parts?

**EDIT**
These parts aren't slow when running the same code on a p2.xlarge aws machine (which has a Tesla K80 GPU)

Comment: `Embedding` is creating a `sparse_tensor` - this a tensor with a lookup structure - this is a relatively slow operation. The first call on `train_on_batch` is creating a `train_function` what last so long.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are ways to speed up theses operations?

Comment: Rather not as this is speeding up training later. Why are you using so many words in your `Embedding`?

Comment: Did you try using different backends?

Comment: No, some of the code is tensorflow specific