# keras startup time (_make_train_function()) very slow on Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB GPU, compared to less powerful GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

follow up to: [keras with tensorflow on GPU machine - some parts are very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47296197/590335)

Running mnist_cnn.py (slightly modified - mainly adding logging) from tensorflow 1.4

running was done using a prebuilt docker image: tensorflow/tensorflow:1.4.0-gpu-py3

on a p2.xlarge aws machine (that has a Tesla K80 GPU) performance is good, the 1st batch (which is dominated by the call to _make_train_function) takes about 2 seconds: (see time stamp for begin batch and end batch)

```
2017-11-19 08:26:26,172 : INFO : fit

2017-11-19 08:26:26,637 : INFO : begin batch
2017-11-19 08:26:26.638409: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2017-11-19 08:26:26.760940: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-19 08:26:26.761478: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.11GiB
2017-11-19 08:26:26.761506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)

2017-11-19 08:26:28,135 : INFO : end batch
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/1
60000/60000 [==============================] - 12s - loss: 0.3526 - acc: 0.8920 - val_loss: 0.0818 - val_acc: 0.9755
Test loss: 0.081773182778
Test accuracy: 0.9755
```

on a p3.2xlarge machine (with a Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB GPU) the same part takes about 10 minutes

```
2017-11-19 08:26:44,120 : INFO : fit

2017-11-19 08:26:44,715 : INFO : begin batch
2017-11-19 08:26:44.716680: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2017-11-19 08:26:46.108295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-19 08:26:46.108775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.53
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 15.77GiB freeMemory: 15.36GiB
2017-11-19 08:26:46.108815: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 7.0)

2017-11-19 08:36:16,552 : INFO : end batch
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/1
60000/60000 [==============================] - 576s - loss: 0.3418 - acc: 0.8949 - val_loss: 0.0769 - val_acc: 0.9772
Test loss: 0.0769035610346
Test accuracy: 0.9772
```

the code that was used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.

Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import cProfile
import os
from tensorflow.contrib import keras
from tensorflow.contrib.keras import backend as K
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='\n%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

class callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
      if batch <= 1:
            logger.info('begin batch')

class callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if batch <= 1:
            logger.info('end batch')

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 1

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
profiler = cProfile.Profile()
profiler.enable()
logger.info('fit')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[callback()])
profiler.dump_stats(os.path.expanduser('~/profiler.pstats'))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a tensorflow version that was build with CUDA 9 appears to solve this issue almost completely: https://github.com/mind/wheels/releases/tag/tf1.4-gpu-cuda9

using this version also requires installing the MKL library - instructions are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation

an explanation why this happens, or a solution that doesn't involves modified versions of tensorflow is still preferred